# Grab Google Maps markers from external JSON

Tags: android, json, api, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working on a map app for android (Google Maps API 2), my goal is two things. There, some of which I managed to do one.

1: Center and follow the user's position. (Successful)
2: Get markers from external JSON source and display on the map. As well as update their position continuously.

I found a piece of code here: https://gist.github.com/saxman/5347195

I put together the code with my code that comes from 1.
Function 1 still works, but logcat says it can not find the file I have specified. That's because it does not exist.
I do not know how the JSON structure should look like, CORS is enabled on the server side to fetch JSON should not be any danger.

However, I wonder if anyone knows how the JSON structure should look like, because I do not know how to figure it out. In addition, so maybe this code is not working, hence the question can be updated if the JSON structure is complete, but the markers do not appear, for example.

**How would the JSON look like? It's impossible for me to figure out.**

MainActivity.java

```
package com.billstrom.yolo;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * 
 */

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Example";

    private static final String SERVICE_URL = "http://codele.se/app/blackcab/drivers.json";

    protected GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available   

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            map = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 



             // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                    onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        }

    }

     @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

     private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
            if (map == null) {
                map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();
                if (map != null) {
                    setUpMap();
                }
            }
        }
     private void setUpMap() {
            // Retrieve the city data from the web service
            // In a worker thread since it's a network operation.
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        retrieveAndAddCities();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot retrive cities", e);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        protected void retrieveAndAddCities() throws IOException {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            final StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                // Connect to the web service
                URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

                // Read the JSON data into the StringBuilder
                int read;
                char[] buff = new char[1024];
                while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                    json.append(buff, 0, read);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to service", e);
                throw new IOException("Error connecting to service", e);
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            }

            // Create markers for the city data.
            // Must run this on the UI thread since it's a UI operation.
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        createMarkersFromJson(json.toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing JSON", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        void createMarkersFromJson(String json) throws JSONException {
            // De-serialize the JSON string into an array of city objects
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                // Create a marker for each city in the JSON data.
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(jsonObj.getString("name"))
                    .snippet(Integer.toString(jsonObj.getInt("population")))
                    .position(new LatLng(
                            jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(0),
                            jsonObj.getJSONArray("latlng").getDouble(1)
                     ))
                );
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();     

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));      


        // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
        tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );      

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

logcat output

```
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968): Error connecting to service
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://codele.se/app/blackcab/drivers.json
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968):     at com.billstrom.yolo.MainActivity.retrieveAndAddCities(MainActivity.java:133)
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968):     at com.billstrom.yolo.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:117)
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968): Cannot retrive cities
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968): java.io.IOException: Error connecting to service
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968):     at com.billstrom.yolo.MainActivity.retrieveAndAddCities(MainActivity.java:143)
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968):     at com.billstrom.yolo.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:117)
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://codele.se/app/blackcab/drivers.json
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968):     at com.billstrom.yolo.MainActivity.retrieveAndAddCities(MainActivity.java:133)
07-01 16:27:40.787: E/Black Cab(17968):     ... 2 more
```

Comment: Could you say your question again, so it's clear? (The output btw is exactly right- this code should do this in this scenario, as you admit yourself.) Thanks.

Comment: Done and done! In bold text, shouldn't be missed now.

Comment: Oh right! I see so you've copied the code for the client and now want to implement your server-side accordingly. Well, that's a novel way round to do it ;). Looks something like ('...' just means etc.): `[{"name": "bobbins driver", "latlng": [90, 180], "population": "012345"}, {"name": "barbara", "latlng": [0, -180], "population": "65432"}...]` but obviously you'd be allowed to change this in the code if you wanted! Don't be afraid! Docs for LatLng seem to be https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng .

Comment: That's so great!:D Any ideas on how to make it "realtime", so the pins update it's position continuously?

Comment: Well, for sure, but one could write a book on that, right? Usually the documentations and tutorials for your client and map API might give some examples? Start with making requests every n seconds and refreshing the map and then maybe it'll be time to start thinking about snazzier protocols etc. (In fact, that'd be a nice question for SO later ;) !).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final answer:

First up, as a word of advice, [Json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json#Schema) is really easy to work with in Java, especially if you use a [mapper](http://jackson.codehaus.org/). So don't go worrying about making your server side data match perfectly with the code sample you found else where- it's really much easier to change things on the client.

Remember to [catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) that `FileNotFoundException`. If something goes wrong in the future, even after having fixed your page, that'll be thrown and crash your app. I personally don't like that particular client for doing it, I much prefer to handle status codes myself. Never assume that http communication that works in QA will remain perfect through time in production: be defensive.

Your json probably would, after all these provisos, look like: `[{"name": "bobbins driver", "latlng": [90, 180], "population": "012345"}, {"name": "barbara", "latlng": [0, -180], "population": "65432"}...]`.

Please see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) for what a `LatLng` is.

As for your follow ups, this topic is too broad. For now, do many requests for map tiles with latlng params and have your server send down only the ones that are nearby. As things get more interesting, if you need real-time updates, there are some protocols designed for this, or you could use the google maps "tile server" pattern with a high tile refresh rate-0[`UrlTileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/UrlTileProvider.html) for a start, or perhaps this can be a future SO question.

Good luck.

Comment: This is the best answer I've got on Stackoverflow. Cheers!